# .NET HttpLogging of request to custom storage

Tags: c#, http, logging, middleware

We work in .NET 6 and want to log all incoming requests. We plan to allow this primarily in DEV and TEST environments but potentially and temporarily also in PROD.

The new HttpLogger sounds like a perfect match. But it will output to the standard ILogger which in our case is Elastic. From GDPR reasons we want to avoid that where potentially sensitive data will be exposed in an uncontrolled way.

Does anyone have another solution:

1. Redirect messages from HttpLogger to other storage
2. Create custom middleware to be able to sniff requests and output to custom storage

I found this interesting post on reading the body twice but was not able to make it work: https://codetalk.in/posts/2022/01/04/read-request-body-multiple-times-in-asp-dot-net-core

Comment: Hello Jakob, please check the approach in this post [HttpLogging - log requests/responses](https://josef.codes/asp-net-core-6-http-logging-log-requests-responses/) in dangerous sections

Comment: Dominik: I actually did read that blog post before I wrote my question. I know it is dangerous to output body. That is why I want to control it and output to other destination. The first approach to create my own logger middleware is fine, but tampering with the body without touching it is tricky. I checked the internal code of HttpLogger. If I can avoid duplication all that I would be happy.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that just by configuration, for example in production app settings, disable HTTP logging for Elastic and enable it for file logger, something like this (really depends on your loggers and configurations):

```json
{
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpLogging.HttpLoggingMiddleware": "Information"
        },
        "Elastic": {
            "IncludeScopes": true,
            "LogLevel": {
                "Default": "Information",
                "Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpLogging.HttpLoggingMiddleware": "None"
            }
        },
        "File": 
        {
            "IncludeScopes": true,
            "LogLevel": {
                "Default": "None",
                "Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpLogging.HttpLoggingMiddleware": "Information"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To be more restrictive, configure `HttpLoggingOptions` for production to not log some fields for example.

Comment: Interesting. We have Serilog but maybe it would still be possible to achieve with configuration?

Comment: There is a NuGet package for reading configuration from appsettings.json [Serilog.Settings.Configuration](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration)